# How do I pass a variable from views to a base html template using Django

Tags: python, django

I have a floatbar with contact details that shows only when the website is opened on a mobile screen. However, there are pages where I do not want them to appear, and I figured I can pass this through context in the respective view classes. What I need to figure out is how do I access this in my base template where this floatbar is called.

I did read a bit about context processors, but I am not sure if I can change the value of the variable being passed.

I would like to be able to access the variable in base html, but also change the value stored within views.py

Comment: In your view, when you call `render()`, one of the arguments is a dictionary of values to pass to the template.

Comment: So if I pass the value in the context, can I access this in the base html template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is create a variable in the view and check for it in the base template. If the variable exists, that code is put onto the base template.

```
{% if flag_variable %}
<p>Whatever HTML code you want to include</p>
 {% endif %}
```

You can treat the base template as the same as your primary template for the purposes of variables.